# SSIS return ORA00928 but query is working fine in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio, ssis, oledb

I have an Oracle SQL query similar to following

```
    Select
       *
    from
        MySchema.Table1 T1
    where
        (
                Recordtime>= to_Date('01/01/2017','yyyymmdd')
            and
                Recordtime<= to_Date('01/01/2022','yyyymmdd')
        )
union
  Select
       *
    from
        MySchema.Table1 T1
    where
            exists(
                select distinct
                    ID
                from
                    MySchema.Table1 T2
                where
                        T2.ID = T1.ID
                    and 
                        T2.Recordtime <> T1.Recordtime
            )
        and 
           not
               (
                    Recordtime>= to_Date('01/01/2017','yyyymmdd')
                and
                    Recordtime<= to_Date('01/01/2022','yyyymmdd')
               )
```

My SSIS keep returns me ORA-00928 on this query
[image]

While my query is completely working fine in SQL Developer.

Do you know what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't know, but - maybe you should use that UNION query as a "source" for another query; something like `select  * from (your current query goes here)`

Answer (score 0):

As the query doesn't knows, where it starts or ends, you can add parenthesis to signalize begin and end

```
    (Select
       *
    from
        MySchema.Table1 T1
    where
        (
                Recordtime>= to_Date('01/01/2017','yyyymmdd')
            and
                Recordtime<= to_Date('01/01/2022','yyyymmdd')
        ))
union
  (Select
       *
    from
        MySchema.Table1 T1
    where
            exists(
                select distinct
                    ID
                from
                    MySchema.Table1 T2
                where
                        T2.ID = T1.ID
                    and 
                        T2.Recordtime <> T1.Recordtime
            )
        and 
           not
               (
                    Recordtime>= to_Date('01/01/2017','yyyymmdd')
                and
                    Recordtime<= to_Date('01/01/2022','yyyymmdd'))
```